# Shell script to delete files older than x days on ftp server

Tags: linux, unix, sh

Have a shell script which connects and puts files to ftp server.
Now trying to delete 2 days older files from the same dir on ftp server.
Tried to use the find command, but getting ?invalid command
find ./*.txt -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;

```
......
ftp -nv <<! >> $FTP_LOG 2>> $FTP_LOG

open xxx
user userid pwd

lcd $FILES_DIR

cd /yyy

put $File1 $File1
put $File2 $File2

find ./*.txt -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;

quit
!
......
```

what else can I try?? Need help with this.

Comment: The `find` command is a shell script command, not an `ftp` command. The standard `ftp` client only supports a very narrow selection of commands. There is really no way to script this within an `ftp` script.  Maybe look at a more capable client like `lftp` or `ncftp`, or write a wrapper to download a list of all files, process it locally, and generate a list of `DELE` commands to submit back to the server.

Comment: See if you have access via `ssh` rather than via `ftp`.  That will give you a shell and you'll be able to do your `find` command in it.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error ,when using the ftp,some linux version cannot recognize
the character "*",replace it with specific one.

Answer (score 0):

FTP will not provide you with a shell, as pointed here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/28568/using-the-find-command-on-the-ftp-server/437649

So you would have to do your search using a `grep` for text files on the client side.

If you have access to `ssh`, the `find` command search files in a directory hierarchy. The first argument you pass should be a directory.

You could search for a pattern, for example files with the txt extension, by using the `-name` option:

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
```

From the man page:

> Don't forget to enclose the pattern in quotes in order to protect it from expansion by the shell.